# Saving multiple dataframes to multiple excel sheets multiple times?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, function, dataframe

I have a function to save multiple dataframes as multiple tables to single excel workbook sheet:

```
def multiple_dfs(df_list, sheets, file_name, spaces):
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_name,engine='xlsxwriter')   
    row = 0
    for dataframe in df_list:
        dataframe.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=sheets,startrow=row , startcol=0)   
        row = row + len(dataframe.index) + spaces + 1
    writer.save()
```

If I call this function multiple times to write multiple tables to multiple sheets, I end up with just one workbook and one sheet, the one that was called last:

```
multiple_dfs(dfs_gfk, 'GFK', 'file_of_tables.xlsx', 1)
multiple_dfs(dfs_top, 'TOP', 'file_of_tables.xlsx', 1)
multiple_dfs(dfs_all, 'Total', 'file_of_tables.xlsx', 1)
```

So in the end I only have `file_of_tables` workbook with only `Total` sheet. I know it's a simple problem, but somehow I just can not think of any elegant solution to this. Can anyone help?

Comment: The `save()` call effectively closes the overall workbook. Move that out of the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the `pandas.ExcelWriter` [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html):

```
You can also append to an existing Excel file:

>>> with ExcelWriter('path_to_file.xlsx', mode='a') as writer:
...     df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet3')
```

The `mode` keyword matters when you're creating an instance of the `ExcelWriter` class.

The `mode='w'` allocates space for the file (which it creates once you call `.save()` or `.close()`) when there isn't one or overwrites one if there is already an existing file.

The `mode='a'` assumes there's an existing file and *appends* on to that file. If you want to keep the structure of your code, you have to add a small line like so:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

def multiple_dfs(df_list, sheets, file_name, spaces):
    arg_mode = 'a' if file_name in os.getcwd() else 'w' # line added
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_name, engine='xlsxwriter', mode=arg_mode) # added mode argument
    row = 0

    for dataframe in df_list:
        dataframe.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=sheets,startrow=row , startcol=0)   
        row = row + len(dataframe.index) + spaces + 1
    writer.save()
```

if you then run the following series of code(s):

```
multiple_dfs(dfs_gfk, 'GFK', 'file_of_tables.xlsx', 1)
multiple_dfs(dfs_top, 'TOP', 'file_of_tables.xlsx', 1)
multiple_dfs(dfs_all, 'Total', 'file_of_tables.xlsx', 1)
```

the last (and second function call) will not overwrite the data currently written in there. Instead what happens is that the first function call ***creates*** the file and then the second and third function call ***append*** to that data. Now, your function should work.

Comment: Love the explanation. Thank you :)

Comment: happy to help :)

Comment: why do you use `with` in your short explanation, but not in the proposed solution?

Comment: @MaartenFabré the `with` in the first code block is from the documentation of `pandas.ExcelWriter` found here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html

Comment: yes. And it is good practise to use it. Why don't you use it in the solution?

Comment: yes it is good practice, but that wasn't part of the question itself. I would prefer to answer only the specific question of "why is this overwriting everything" and not overstep the boundaries of the question to "pythonic way to do this". Notice I said: "if you want to keep the structure of your code".

Comment: use os.listdir(os.getcwd()) to check if files is in current directory. os.getcwd() will only return the path.

Answer (score 2):

Get `writer` outside function with [`with`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#writing-excel-files-to-disk):

```
def multiple_dfs(df_list, sheets, writer, spaces):
    row = 0
    for dataframe in df_list:
        dataframe.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=sheets,startrow=row , startcol=0)   
        row = row + len(dataframe.index) + spaces + 1
    writer.save()

with pd.ExcelWriter('file_of_tables.xlsx') as writer:
    multiple_dfs(dfs_gfk, 'GFK', writer, 1)
    multiple_dfs(dfs_top, 'TOP', writer, 1)
    multiple_dfs(dfs_all, 'Total', writer, 1)
```