# How to write different dataframes into seperate sheets of a csv file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two different `panda.DataFrame` (`df1` and `df2`). I want to write each dataframe into a separate sheet in the CSV file. In this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30829806/6494707), all dataframes are written in the same sheet.

Comment: The CSV format does not support "separate sheets"; please see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29615196/is-csv-with-multi-tabs-sheet-possible

Comment: CSV is just a text file, it doesn't know about `sheet`. If you mean `excel`, you can see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56034923/saving-multiple-dataframes-to-multiple-excel-sheets-multiple-times).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSV files don't support sheets. 
You can use pd.to_excel and ExcelWriter to write in the same excel file:

first, install the **openpyxl** module if you don't have

```
python -m pip install openpyxl
```

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx') as writer:
    df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='df1')
    df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='df2')
```

Documentation here:
[Pandas Docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html)

Comment: Is there also an option to write `writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')` ? I'm trying that right now and it's not working for me

Comment: Hi tamtam. You installed/imported openpyxl lib? It works for me here. Share your code if you can.